# Peaks on buck converter voltage

Tags: buck

I have noticed, that my +12V Buck Converter LMR16006X ([Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr16006.pdf?ts=1596098436526&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLMR16006)) has some voltage peaks with a constant frequency for any input voltage from +15V to +48V. This peaks are also independent of the load and I'm not sure, where it really comes from. I think, that I have choosen a wrong inductor, but at the moment I cannot prove it.

[image]
[image]

- There are no peaks on the input voltage
- The peaks occur with around 100ms in between directly at the +12V output
- There is always a double peak with around 1.5ms in between

So can this happen, if the inductor goes into saturation? I have the following components:

[image]

From the calculations in the datasheet I get 100uH as the minimum inductor value. So this should be good, but I'm unsure about the saturation current, my inductor seems to have only 420mA, I have not seen that when I have chosen it. Could be this the cause of the problem or may the tolerance of 20% be the reason, such that my inductor may have only 80uH and so less than needed?

The Layout looks like this and should be fine:

[image]

Comment: What is your load? Is the load doing something like consuming current every 100ms, for 1.5ms?

Comment: There is a uC on the board, but this also occurs when resetet

Comment: Ok I found the problem, it was the ESP32 on the board, that was not flashed when delivered. So, somehow the ESP32 has this 100ms current draw for 1.5ms when not initially flashed.

Comment: Probably there is some chinese spionage firmware initially on the ESP32^^'